# How to avoid congestion of ticks in y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The figure attached here has too many ticks in y axis and is congested.I dont want to change the y axis to any other scale.I want to hide the every second number in y axis.Is this possible?,which means [5,15,25.....] will be hidden.

Is there any other approach to avoid congestion in y axis?

[image: y axis congestion in matplot figure]

```
pl.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
pl.scatter(x=T1['Current_Sim_rcs_obj1'], y=T1['Final Mean_Range'])
pl.xlabel('Truth RCS [dBsm]')
pl.xlim(-40, 5)
pl.ylim(0, 280)
pl.grid()
pl.ylabel('RUT_Range[m]')
pl.xticks(np.arange(-45, 15, 5))
pl.yticks(np.arange(0, 281, 10))
pl.show()
```

I tried to add the below line to the above code,which didn't worked as expected.

```
pl.axes().yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
```

Comment: Please add a minimal, reproducible code example to create the same plot that you attached as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use matplotlib's `yticks()` [function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) to get all the ticks (locations) and labels. Then you can modify the two lists based on some criteria. For the criteria you give, we can ignore every second tick and label:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure()  # Create a figure
locs, labels = plt.yticks()  # Get the current locations and labels

locs = locs[0::2]  # Choose every other location
labels = labels[0::2]  # Choose every other label

plt.yticks(locs, labels)  # Set new yticks and labels
```

I could imagine other cases where where the criteria are based on the length of `locs`. In fact, that's probably what `matplotlib` is doing behind the scenes already. It has some heuristic which is trying to choose a good length for `locs` based on the size of the plot and the scale of the data.

Comment: i tried to do this and got the following error
`
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'YTick' and 'YTick` 
'

Comment: It sounds like you may be doing some extra logic on `locs`? The `[0::2]` syntax should choose every other tick in the list. Are you modifying `locs` in some other way?

This could also be a matplotlib version difference. I'm testing with version `3.3.4`